# Working with observableArray to toggle values on click binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am new to knockout and working with the tutorials but not having luck.

I'm trying to set an array of images to behave similar to a group of checkboxes.  They initially should all be set to 'true' in the array 'self.brands' and have the class '.active'.  On click event, I would like them to toggle them true or false and set a class from .active to .deactive

The array 'self.brands' represents 4 properties.  ID, imagepath, alt tag, checked (true or false).  When you click the image it should toggle true/false value, set the css from .active {opacity:1} to deactive {opacity:0.2}.

here is the self.brands observable array:

```
self.brands = ko.observableArray([["1",'acdsee.jpg','ACD See',"true"], "2",'amazon.jpg','Amazon',"true"], ["3",'aol.jpg','AOL',"true"], ["4",'cisco.jpg','Cisco',"true"];
```

Here is the html for images:

```
<a href="#">Select All</a> | <a href="#">Deselect all</a>
<br />
<div id="brands">
<ul data-bind="foreach: brands" class="brands">
                  <li data-bind="click: $parent.setBrand,
               css: { active: $data == $root.chosenBrandId() }"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: $parent.setBrand"> <img data-bind="attr:{src: $data[1], alt: $data[2]}" /></a> 
               </li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

css :

```
.active {opacity:1}
.deactive {opacity:0.2}
```

Knockout code:

```
self.chosenBrandId = ko.observable();

self.setBrand = function(brand) { 

self.chosenBrandId(brand); 
};
```

I'm having issues setting this up. Currently when you click an image it only applies the .active class to one image at a time.  When I try to get the value of self.chosenBrandId(brand) it returns [object, object]. So am not understanding how would I set the value inside the chosenBrandID to true, I tried

```
self.chosenBrandId(brand)[3];
```

but that returns undefined, so am wondering how to set the value and even what parameters can be retrieved within the "brand" variable that returns [object,object] ;

Would like this to behave in the following ways:

1) onclick of individual image toggle between .active and .deactive class?

2) onclick  of individual image change the boolean true/false value of the self.brands array?

3) create a function to change all images css and array values from .active and true or .deactive and false, when you click link "Select All" or "Deselect All"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your CSS class "active" logic is wrong, your code only allows one to be set at a time.
(Looks like you also have duplicated the click binding).

If you want to toggle these like check boxes, the true/false property should be a ko.observable.
I've modified the code as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/JvqHs/

```
var self = this;
self.brands = ko.observableArray([{
    id: "1",
    img: 'acdsee.jpg',
    name: 'ACD See',
    active: ko.observable(true)
}, {
    id: "2",
    img: 'amazon.jpg',
    name: 'Amazon',
    active: ko.observable(true)
}, {
    id: "3",
    img: 'aol.jpg',
    name: 'AOL',
    active: ko.observable(true)
}, {
    id: "4",
    img: 'cisco.jpg',
    name: 'Cisco',
    active: ko.observable(true)
}]);

self.setBrand = function (brand) {
    var state = !brand.active();
    brand.active(state);
};
```

Comment: +1 and a little explanation: the `observableArray` only observes *which* elements an array contains, not the *state* of those elements.

Comment: Thanks, you just opened up my world!

Comment: I'm curious about this piece of code: "$("html")[0]" from ko.applyBindings(new Model(), $("html")[0]), how come it's included?

Comment: It's the jQuery way of getting the dom <body> tag.  While it's not specifically needed in this case, I think it's a good habit to bind your KO models to specific part fo the dom.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, how do I get the select All and deselect all links to work,  I understand this part, <a class="selectall" data-bind="click: selectAllBrands">Select All</a>, how do I set up the function selectAllBrands()?  This is where I get confused in knockout approach... if this was javascript I would setup a for loop to cycle through the array and set all the values of active to true.. I don't know how to deal with this this in knockout, please help!!! :)

Comment: This is exactly what you'd do in Knockout - but *outside the DOM* as an operation on your model (and triggered by a click handler, etc).   Updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9UTVL/1/

Comment: Wow thanks for that!   This is what threw me off  self.brands().forEach(function(brand) {
            brand.active(true)
        })  ... the "forEach",  never knew how to formulate that syntax,  I've only seen the foreach applied to the data-bind but not in the function. where did you learn that? is that knockout call or a javascript call?